# Error using Firebase Storage in Firebase emulator

Tags: android, firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-tools

Writing an Android app that needs to access thumbnails on Firebase Storage Emulator. Images created using the Firebase Resize-Image function.

The link for each thumbnail is a StorageReference based on the bucket, auth and filename:

Example:

```
var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://my-bucket/").getReference(authID + filename)
```

These created urls are identical to the link for the thumbnails on Firebase Storage Emulator.

Next step is downloadUrl as follows:

```
storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener {
  fileUri = it.result 
 
  Picasso.get().load(fileUri).resize(200,0).into(holder.binding.imageView)
}
```

Error shows when this line is called:

```
fileUri = it.result
```

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: User does not have permission to access this object.

Bucket rules on Firebase Storage Emulator are set like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Bucket should be set to accept any request?

The tokenized, public links from the original images are retained in Realtime Database and the Android app can access those without issue. Example link:
http://10.0.2.2:9199/v0/b/....

Comment: Reviewed many options and ultimately was unable to make any of them work, and, switched from trying to use the "other" bucket to using a separate path inside the default bucket for the thumbnails produced by the firebase storage image-resize function.